# PHP extension to 5.3.15

Tags: php, search

Version of 5.3.15

I'm looking for such extensions (.dll file):

1. php_intl.dll
2. php_apc.dll

It was under this version.
Thanks.

Comment: http://windows.php.net/download/

Comment: http://windows.php.net/download/#php-5.3-nts-VC9-x86 - 5.3.19

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is also an archive there...

http://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/archives/php-5.3.15-nts-Win32-VC9-x86.zip

Full list of previous releases:

http://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/archives/